# pct_change between 2 columns in Pandas, with row offset

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
               Date_Time   Open  Close
0    2004-05-10 16:00:00  12.88  12.54
1    2004-05-11 16:00:00  12.87  12.68
2    2004-05-12 16:00:00  12.79  12.88
3    2004-05-13 16:00:00  12.84  12.88
4    2004-05-14 16:00:00  12.64  12.88
5    2004-05-17 16:00:00  12.72  12.68
```

What I need to do is compute the change, as a percentage, between the `Close` of a row and the `Open` of the **next one** (not the same row!). This should start from row 0, so that row 5 should contain NaN. Like this (with placeholder values):

```
               Date_Time   Open  Close  Overnight_change
0    2004-05-10 16:00:00  12.88  12.54  123
1    2004-05-11 16:00:00  12.87  12.68  123
2    2004-05-12 16:00:00  12.79  12.88  123
3    2004-05-13 16:00:00  12.84  12.88  123
4    2004-05-14 16:00:00  12.64  12.88  123
5    2004-05-17 16:00:00  12.72  12.68  NaN
```

I'm trying this:

```
overnight_change = (csv_data['Open'].loc[1:] - csv_data['Close']) / csv_data['Close']
df.assign(overnight_change=overnight_change)
```

However, this gives:

```
               Date_Time   Open  Close  Overnight_change
0    2004-05-10 16:00:00  12.88  12.54  NaN
1    2004-05-11 16:00:00  12.87  12.68  123
2    2004-05-12 16:00:00  12.79  12.88  123
3    2004-05-13 16:00:00  12.84  12.88  123
4    2004-05-14 16:00:00  12.64  12.88  123
5    2004-05-17 16:00:00  12.72  12.68  123
```

How can I offset the assign operation? Or is there any other better way to do it?

I've also tried to call `csv_data['Open'].loc[1:].reset_index` but this gives:

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3776, placement implies 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
overnight_change = (df['Open'].shift(-1) - df['Close']) / df['Close']
df = df.assign(overnight_change=overnight_change)
print (df)
             Date_Time   Open  Close  overnight_change
0  2004-05-10 16:00:00  12.88  12.54          0.026316
1  2004-05-11 16:00:00  12.87  12.68          0.008675
2  2004-05-12 16:00:00  12.79  12.88         -0.003106
3  2004-05-13 16:00:00  12.84  12.88         -0.018634
4  2004-05-14 16:00:00  12.64  12.88         -0.012422
5  2004-05-17 16:00:00  12.72  12.68               NaN
```

Or:

```
#store shifted data to Series for only once run shift
c = df['Close'].shift(-1)
overnight_change = (df['Open'] - c) / c
df = df.assign(overnight_change=overnight_change)
print (df)
             Date_Time   Open  Close  overnight_change
0  2004-05-10 16:00:00  12.88  12.54          0.015773
1  2004-05-11 16:00:00  12.87  12.68         -0.000776
2  2004-05-12 16:00:00  12.79  12.88         -0.006988
3  2004-05-13 16:00:00  12.84  12.88         -0.003106
4  2004-05-14 16:00:00  12.64  12.88         -0.003155
5  2004-05-17 16:00:00  12.72  12.68               NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56042327/3284713) or shift the resulting series

```
df['overnight_change']=df['overnight_change'].shift(-1)
```